# Which is the Best for session id out of the following two approaches

Tags: java

I want to save a id as session id which should not hacked by anyone.

Example1:

```
java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

Example2:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom()
new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this -> http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=56

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.util.UUID` uses `SecureRandom` internally.

No need to roll your own. Approach 1 will work just fine.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Went through the code. it uses SecureRandom ng = Holder.numberGenerator. Thanks for the quick reply.